# How the react-native documentation is made?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, documentation, docusaurus

I know the code is in here: `https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website` and it uses Docusaurus, but, the markdown is automatically generated from the code or it was all written manually?
And if it's automatically generated, what is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are written manually using markdown. Docusaurus takes that markdown and generates the HTML/JS which is published.

The markdown is available in the repo in the [docs folder](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/tree/master/docs).

Comment: It would be nice if you could add a link for this markdown source repository to improve your answer and also to confirm your statement

Comment: Isn't a static documentation easy to be outdated? What they do to maintain it?